# How do you detach a remote screen session in byobu (tmux)?

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen, byobu

I am currently in a byobu-tmux session and am ssh'ed into a screen session.  How do I detach the remote screen session without detaching byobu-tmux session?  Some things to note, I can't run byobu-config because I'm on osx and don't have python-newt (w/ snack) installed.  And, I've run byobu-ctrl-a in Emacs mode, but that doesn't seem to allow me to ctrl-a d out of the remote screen session.

Answer (score 24):

You should be able to double-escape with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>.

To send a detach message to the inner byobu-screen session, press:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: I tried it, but second time I press `Ctrl-a` I get moved to 0 window in my local byobu session. how could I do any operation in the remote screen session?

Comment: Ctrl+a Ctrl+a just toggles between last two windows. What is double-escape and how do you do it? Only pressing Ctrl+a does not do it. Ctrl+a, Ctrl+a, d only results in sending the letter 'd' to the terminal.

Comment: 'Ctrl+a a' sends ctrl+a

Comment: What if I disabled `ctrl+a` when I setup byobu?

Comment: So if anyone is confused like me, Ctrl + a and then d worked for me.

Answer (score 23):

It is easy when you use tmux commands:

```
byobu-tmux detach
byobu-tmux
```

or even just:

```
byobu detach
byobu
```

Comment: I had a remote user connected to my screen that I had to detach; this did the trick but you might have to issue the commands multiple times and/or resize your window if byubu is restricting it to narrower than the width of your terminal.

Comment: In one case something like this did it for me over ssh: `$ byobu detach; byobu detach`

Answer (score 20):

Try letting go of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> after the first <kbd>a</kbd>, so the sequence is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>. Man screen:

> C-a C-a     (other)       Toggle  to  the  window  displayed
>   previously.  Note that this
>                                binding defaults to the command character typed twice,  unless
>                                overridden.   For instance, if you use the option "-e]x", this
>                                command becomes "]]".
>
> C-a a       (meta)        Send the command character (C-a) to
>   window.  See  escape  com‐
>                                mand.

Or if you're using tmux instead of screen for Byobu, try just <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>. Byobu's default prefix key is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>, so if you're using that default, doubling up the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> keystroke would not be necessary.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/309215/106100

Comment: Very nice tips, works for me while all other suggestions failed

Answer (score 17):

I was able to do this by listing all clients inside the current client:

```
$ byobu list-clients
/dev/pts/67: 1 [80x24 xterm] (utf8) 
/dev/pts/70: 1 [157x48 xterm-256color] (utf8)
```

Then detach the remote client (determined based on screen size):

```
$ byobu detach -t /dev/pts/67
```

Now I can use my full window size

Comment: I don't think this answers the original question, but it's what I was looking for! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138211/how-do-i-disconnect-all-other-users-in-tmux answers more directly.

Answer (score 7):

perhaps not relevant to tmux but for byobu, I found the following command to be very helpful: detach all sessions except the current one:

`/usr/lib/byobu/include/tmux-detach-all-but-current-client`

hope this helps

Comment: doesn't answer the original question but it answers my question! similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30678503/109747

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the prefix of your local session if it conflicts with the remote session. For example, if both are using CTRL+A then you'd be in trouble. You can either send a raw command (there's a sequence for that, but I can't remember it), or go the easy route and remap your local session to Ctrl+B, then you can input Ctrl+A that will get routed to the remote session. Also not related to tmux but the ssh connection itself you can input "~." and it'll disconnect from the ssh session. Hope it helps.

Comment: Not sure if there's a way to switch the prefix of the current local session, I resolved the issue by closing the local session, switching the config by running byobu-ctrl-a, and then starting a new byobu session

Answer (score -1):

I've been an avid user of byobu on Linux for the best part of a decade. After struggling with configuring the brew install of byobu on OSX for most of these years, I finally managed to setup my byobu configs in a round about way. First I executed this:

```
echo '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' | sudo tee /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

Then I ran the byobu config file:

```
byobu-config
```

Finally I cleaned up

```
sudo rm /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

Python crashed along the way with a few pop-ups, however, byobu now works for me as it should. I do need to repeat these steps when I want to change config again though... still looking for a cleaner solution.