# How do I disconnect all other users in tmux?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I've got a tmux session where the window is too small because some user somewhere is connected.

How do I tell tmux to disconnect all connected users?

Answer (score 372, accepted):

You can use `<prefix> D` <sup>(where prefix is `C-b` by default)</sup>, to chose which clients to detach; it will also list they col/lines as well as the last used time. Note the uppercase `D`, i.e. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.

You could also use tmux's `detach-client` option

```
 detach-client [-P] [-a] [-s target-session] [-t target-client]
               (alias: detach)
         Detach the current client if bound to a key, the client specified
         with -t, or all clients currently attached to the session speci-
         fied by -s.  The -a option kills all but the client given with
         -t.  If -P is given, send SIGHUP to the parent process of the
         client, typically causing it to exit.
```

either from `<prefix>:`followed by `detach [options]` or on the command line inside tmux with `tmux detach [options]`

Comment: `<prefix> D` be careful,  the **majuscule D** is important  here !!   (I spend some frustrating time detaching my current client before realizing it :D )

Comment: Thank you.
I usually [Ctrl-b] [D] [up] [enter]

Comment: I think I'm going to start using `prefix`+'D' so I don't forget about it. Worked like a charm.

Comment: In a tmux session, `tmux detach-client -a` will detach all other clients except the current one. I often mistype `prefix-D` so I prefer this approach. I even have a function `detachothers () { tmux detach-client -a; `.

Comment: ...and in case you haven't come across the word before, "majuscule" means "upper-case".

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder how to exit from "Ctrl+D" mode? [ESC] does not work. I need it when I push Ctrl+D and see only one client (myself)

Comment: @AlexanderChzhen a single 'q' press does the trick for exiting the selection menu without choosing a session to end.

Answer (score 183):

`tmux a -dt <session-name>`

```
a=attach
d=detach other clients (so only you can attach to this session)
t=target
```

Answer (score 13):

I'll break out [@PEdroArthur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695507/pedroarthur)'s great comment into a separate answer since it directly answers the most common use case: "being within a tmux session and wanting to disconnect all other sessions"

Run this from ***within*** your tmux session:

```
tmux detach-client -a
```